# Duplication of models with multiple nested & non-nested belongs_to relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amoeba-gem

Apologies if the title isn't accurate, I had a difficult time distilling this question into a single line. I'm using the [amoeba gem](https://github.com/amoeba-rb/amoeba) and trying to figure out if it's possible to associate a duplicated model with multiple belongs_to relationships.

For instance:

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :floors
  has_many    :layout_groups
end

class Floor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :building
  has_many    :units
end

class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :floor
  has_many    :layouts
end

class Layout < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :unit
  belongs_to :layout_group
end


class LayoutGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :building
  has_many    :layouts
end
```

As you can see, `Layouts` belongs to both `Unit` and `LayoutGroup`. If I'm making a complete duplicate of `Building`, how do I associate `layouts` with both `units` and `layout_groups` but also ensure that two sets of `layouts` are not created in the process?

Im open to using a non-amoeba solution, I just stated there as it was suggested.